# Angular 2: pass a value to the route data resolve

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to write a `DataResolver` service that will allow the Angular 2 router to preload data before initializing my component.

The resolver needs to call different API endpoints to fetch data appropriate to the route being loaded.  Rather than having a resolver for each of my many components, I'm building one generic resolver. Thus, I'd like to pass custom input in the route definition that points to the correct endpoint. For instance, consider these routes:

**app.routes.ts**

```
appRoutes = [
  {
     path: 'project/:id',
     component: ProjectComponent,
     resolve: { data: DataResolver }
  },
  {
     path: 'store/:id',
     component: StoreComponent,
     resolve: { data: DataResolver }
  }
]
```

In the first instance, the resolver will need to call `/path/to/resource1/id`. In the second case, `/path/to/resource2/id`. Ideally, I would pass the endpoint as an argument in the route definition that would then be available in the `DataResolver` constructor.

Can this be done with a generic resolver class?

`Angular 2.0.1` written in `Typescript 2.0.3`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I don't know about making it available in the constructor, without using DI. But if you want it available in the `resolve` method, you could just add a `data` property in the route definition, and this would make it available to the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`

```
{
  path: 'project/:id',
  component: ProjectComponent,
  resolve: { data: DataResolver },
  data: { path: 'project/:id' }
}

class DataResolve implements Resolve<string> {
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return route.data['path'];
  }
}
```

Comment: in the last line -- `route.data['path']`, will `:id` be automatically replaced with the current route parameter or will it be the literal string `project/:id`?

Comment: No. I guess I misunderstood your question. I though that's what you wanted. Just get the `url` from the `route`. It will be an `UrlSegment[]`. `url[1].path` should have the id, and `url[0].path` should be `project`

Comment: I could have done a better job to explain. `resolve()` will call the API and return the Observable that will emit the data returned by the server. My challenge was that the API endpoint to call depends on the component whose data is getting resolved. Your answer is helpful though. I can use the `data` property of the route to make custom inputs available to `resolve()`. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha but what if you have multiple resolvers for a route but want a different path for each of them?

Comment: I found this post is helpful. https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/#access-to-route-params

Comment: `route.data['path'];` only returns this  `'project/:id'`, BUT I WANT THE CURRENT ID OF URL. So, I GOT THE SOLUTION... use `route.paramMap.get('id')`. Hope this Helps : )

Answer (score 4):

This answer solved my problem, but I also needed this to be applied in case the route has multiple resolvers.

eg.

```
   {
    path: 'transactions/showcase/edit/:id',
    component: ClientsTransactionsFormComponent,
    resolve: {
      clients: Resolver,
      clientTransaction: Resolver,
      clientTransactionTypes: Resolver
    },
```

In that case I solved my issue by passing an array in data.

```
data: ['Clients/GetAll', 'ClientTransactions/GetByID/', 'ClientTransactionTypes/GetAll']
```

and also modified my resolver like this..

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    let row = [];
    let id = "";

    Object.keys(route.data).forEach(e => {
      row.push(route.data[e]);
    })

    let path: string = row[0];
    delete row[0];

    route.data = row;

    if (path.lastIndexOf('/') == path.length - 1) {
      id = route.params['id'];
    }

    return this._httpService.httpGet(this.baseUrl + path + id);
  }
```

hope it helps anybody.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id as the following snippet:

```js
class DataResolve implements Resolve<string> {
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:   RouterStateSnapshot) {
    console.log(parseInt(route.paramMap.get('id'), 10))
  }
}
```

Please notice that type of route.paramMap.get('id') will be string.